# Insert "between" numeric keys in array php

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am currently writing a class which is going to handle output from other objects. The class constructs a numeric array at the first dimension with HTML *"fields"*, containing tag, attributes and content. Content will be then a numeric array again for HTML tags nesting. If `'Tag'` is NULL, it is considered direct text.

```
$output = array( //Numeric array
    array( //Associative array 
        'Tag' => 'h3',
        'Attributes' => 'id=SomeTitle',
        'Contents' => array (), //Numeric array again, same as first dimension,
    ),
    array( //Associative array 
        'Tag' => 'p',
        'Attributes' => 'id=someID',
        'Contents' => array (), //Numeric array again, same as first dimension
    ),
);
```

The question now is: is there an **easy way** to insert data on an already defined position? Let's say I want a new associative array to be placed in `$output[1]` and all other indexes equal and higher then to be incremented by one.

I know that I could write a method that iterate over the array in reverse and increase all those indexes. It's just that I'm wondering if I overlooked anything in the PHP handbook, that handles the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_splice`:
<kbd>[array_splice documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)</kbd>

> array array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length [, mixed $replacement = array() ]] )
>
> Removes the elements designated by offset and length from the input array, and replaces them with the elements of the replacement array, if supplied.

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 3, 0, "purple");
// $input is now array("red", "green",
//          "blue", "purple", "yellow");
```